# How can we draw these graphs like in this book?

Tags: graphics, plot, graphs, technical-drawing

Can you show me which tools we can use to draw the graphs look like in this book? (see below figure). Sorry, I don't know exactly where I can post this question.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Your question has been migrated here as we might be able to help. To do that, though, we'll need to know what software you've got available to you.

Comment: @JosephWright: thanks, I've used LaTeX but it's quite complicated for me to draw freely graphs like in above figure. I wonder if there are other apps to do this job?

Comment: Ah, I have found the below answer from Robert. :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use several plotting  packages, some of them very sophisticated.

My package `xpicture` is specially designed for mathematical plottings.

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xpicture}
\begin{document}
  \newlpoly{\p}{-5}{3}              % Defines y=-5+3x
  \renewcommand{\Pictlabelsep}{0.2}
  \setlength{\unitlength}{.75cm}
  \begin{Picture}(-1.5,-1.5)(6,6)
      \cartesianaxes(-1.5,-1.5)(5.5,5.5)
      \xVECTOR(5.5,0)(5.6,0)
      \xVECTOR(0,5.5)(0,5.6)
      \Put[E](5.5,0){$x$}
      \Put[N](0,5.5){$y$}
      \pictcolor{cyan}
      {\thicklines
         \PlotFunction{\p}{1.5}{3.25} % Plots p between x=1.5 and x=3.25
         \Put(2,1){\circle*{0.2}}
         \Put(3,4){\circle*{0.2}}}
      \Polyline(2,1)(3,1)(3,4)
      \Put[SE](2,1){$\Delta x=1$}
      \Put[E](3,2.5){$\Delta y=3$}
      \p{3.1}{\x}{\Dx}
      \Put[E](3.1,\x){$\leftarrow$ slope 3}
  \end{Picture}
\end{document}
```

[image: slope of a line]